# Connection to MongoDB via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reactjs, gulp

I am using Gulp building system. When I try to connect to my local `MongoDB` using `mongoose` I got error  `mongoose.connect is not a function`.

Connection code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Comment: You're trying to use Mongoose from a browser, which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. Are you sure you correctly installed mongoose?

```
npm install --save mongoose
```

Comment: Yes, when I put this code in my gulpfile.js it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that you're using mongoose directly in react ?

Mongoose is a node module: "elegant mongodb object modeling for node.js".